# Input a text by the command in newenvironment

Tags: macros, environments

I want to have something like this but I can't figure out how I can achieve it.

```
\begin{sidenote}
    Text
\end{sidenote}
```

I want to create this environment using `newenvironment`. What I want to do is the text in the begin-end should be fed to the command `\marginnote`. So I need to get

```
\marginnote{Text}
```

whenever I put the text in a `sidenote` environment.

Comment: There is a package for sidenotes, as far as I know

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ,marginnote}
\NewEnviron{sidenote}{\marginnote{\BODY}}
\begin{document}
This is text
\begin{sidenote}
Here is my sidenote text
\end{sidenote}
More text
\end{document}
```

[image]